# Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Tags: sql-server-2008r2-express

alter table Garantor alter column [Birth Date] int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this (you'll need to create a new column, update it with a conversion, drop the old one then rename the new one with old one's name)

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Garantor
ADD newBirthDate int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 -- NULL and DEFAULT as required
GO

UPDATE dbo.Garantor
SET newBirthDate = CAST([Birth Date] AS int) -- or CONVERT function, it will do the same
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Garantor
DROP COLUMN [Birth Date]
GO

SP_RENAME 'dbo.Garantor.newBirthDate', 'dbo.Garantor.[Birth Date]'
GO
```

Comment: If the column are all nulls, you can change it to varchar then change it to int. That will work.

Answer (score 1):

Convert does not work for me.
Cast does not work either.
To change the data type of a column, here is the code that worked.
Change the "date" type to the "int" type, keeping only the year.

This works for me:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Garantor]
ADD [newBirthDate] int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
GO

UPDATE [dbo].[Garantor]
SET [newBirthDate] = DATEPART(yyyy,[Birth Date])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Garantor]
DROP COLUMN [Birth Date]
GO

SP_RENAME 'dbo.Garantor.newBirthDate', 'dbo.Garantor.[Birth Date]'
GO
```

An alternative solution is:

```
= YEAR([Birth Date])
```

And if you have an index in your table:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Garantor]
ADD [newBirthDate] int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
GO

UPDATE [dbo].[Garantor]
SET [newBirthDate] = DATEPART(yyyy,[Birth Date])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Garantor] DROP CONSTRAINT [UQ__Garantor__1C123681D17FE31B] -- [UQ__Garantor__1C123681D17FE31B] change with your
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Garantor]
DROP COLUMN [Birth Date]
GO

SP_RENAME 'dbo.Garantor.newBirthDate', 'dbo.Garantor.[Birth Date]'
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Garantor] ADD UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Birth Date] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was my first response on Stackoverflow. Modified according to recommendations. Well, I hope.